# How to return data to client using beforeSignIn Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-classroom

I need 5 properties from Firebase Authentication in order to Authenticate with the Google Classroom API.

I can get the user's `accessToken` after signing in with popup as follows:

```js
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  const SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly',
    'openid', ...etc
  ];

  for (let scope of SCOPES) {
    provider.addScope(scope);
  }
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
  });

  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then(async (result) => {
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);

      const token = credential.accessToken;
  }
)
```

But I also need the `refreshToken`, `clientId`, `clientSecret` and `expiryTime`.

I know that I can access a few of these by using the `beforeSignIn` cloud function with the appropriate settings checked off in the firebase console.

```js
exports.beforeSignIn = functions.auth.user()
.beforeSignIn((user, context) => {
  const refreshToken = context.credential.refreshToken;
  const expiryTime = context.credential.expirationTime;
 
  // How do I return these to the client?
});
```

I also note that `credential.secret` is always empty and that `clientId` is not present anywhere in the `user` or `context` arguments of the cloud function.

If it is not possible to return these from the Function, is there any other way I can get these 5 properties from Firebase Authentication on the web, so that I can authenticate the Google Classroom API in an external service?

I am using Firebase Admin version: 11.0
Using Google Identity Platform for Firebase Auth